# How to use password form for other forms on button click within main form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've created a form which has password authentication through a database. However, I do not want a login function, I just want to authenticate access to other forms from a button click within the main form. So how would I call the password form to authenticate access to other forms on button click?

Password form:

```
public partial class GetPass : Form
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=BooyaaBrowser;Integrated Security=True");

    private TextBox PasstextBox;
    private Button btn_confirm;
    private Label EnterPass;

    public GetPass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sdf = new SqlDataAdapter ("select count (*)from password where password = '" + PasstextBox.Text + "'",con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sdf.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Password correct");
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Booyaa Says Wrong Password", "Wrong Password", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Messaage ");
             }
        }
```

One of the button click form:

```
private void Blocklist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Blocklist frm1 = new Blocklist();
    frm1.Show();
}
```

Comment: never store passwords in plain text. and you are askin for sql injection attacks!

Comment: @DanielA.White the password is to simply stop kids maximum up 10//11-year-olds, as this a children's browser, so the passwords stop access to parental tools. Therefore, no sensitive data or any threat from such things.

Comment: Never too tired to see those awesome emtpy catch clauses.

Comment: @UweKeim Sorry about that, there you go.

Comment: In your `GetPass` form, set [this.DialogResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) to either "OK" or "Cancel" based on the authentication results.  This will cause the form to be dismissed.  Back in the calling form, you'd display `GetPass` with `ShowDialog()` and trap the return value.  This will let you know the results of the authentication...

Comment: @Idle_Mind THANKK YOUUU

Answer (score 2):

For avoiding confusion i use the **MainForm** and **PopupForm** and in the Program.cs file make MainForm loads firstly.

```
    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopupForm popup = new PopupForm();
        popup.FormClosing += (o, i) => {
            if (!popup.passwordFound)
                this.Close();
        };
        popup.ShowDialog();
   }
```

and in popup form that has PasstextBox and btnCheckPassword

```
public bool passwordFound = false; 
public void btnCheckPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   // your sql actions:
   try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sdf = new SqlDataAdapter ("select count (*)from password where password = '" + PasstextBox.Text + "'",con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sdf.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Password correct");
            this.Hide();
            passwordFound = true;
            // this.Close()  you can also.
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Booyaa Says Wrong Password", "Wrong Password", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Messaage ");
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error under ".Text" saying object does not contain definition.

Comment: You mean `PasstextBox.Text` ?

Comment: yeah, even though I used  public object PasstextBox { get; private set; }

Comment: You have a sql table named `password` and in that you have a column name `password` also?

Comment: yes, I do. Also I placed Public void CheckPassword method in the main form and button declaration in the Blocklist form.

Comment: I tried running the code in the GetPass form and it works fine there.

Comment: I edited the answer. the `CheckPassword` must be in blockList form.

Comment: if I put a Passtextbox in BlockList then I would have to enter the password in that. However, what I want is the GetPass form to popup in front of the BlockList form in order to allow access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136104/discussion-between-farzin-kanzi-and-sharabeel-shah).